# How to show ideals factor modulo an elliptic curve?

Tags: polynomials, ideals, elliptic-curves, rational-functions

How to show ideals factor modulo an elliptic curve? That is $\langle f\rangle= \prod \langle x-x_p,y-y_p\rangle $   where $x_p$, $y_p$ is the intersection of $f$ with the elliptic curve points counted with multiplicity.

What's the easiest way to show this using mostly basic ring theory

Also is this true for other curves besides elliptic

Comment: Because (affine) elliptic curves are smooth (affine) curves. Smooth affine curves are all [Dedekind domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) and thus have the ideal factorization property.

Comment: @jgon is there something more elementary?